# Who provides Carnet de Passage for Indian vehicles?

Tags: india, automobiles, carnet-de-passage

Under which government department and which law the Carnet is issued in India ?

I have already visited Nepal and Bhutan on bike. Both the countries don't need any Carnet from Indians. Now, I want to go Pakistan on my bike.

What I understood after googling is - Carnet is 'MUST' to visit any country on your vehicle.

I came to know that Automobile Association of India is the sole authority to provide Carnet de passage. But they charge a huge amount of Rs 10,000 for a vehicle (2/4 wheels).

Is it necessary to get a Carnet de passage if I want to travel in Pakistan on my Indian bike?

Cant I get a cheaper Carnet from a Government office ?

Links:

- http://delhitonepalonbike.blogspot.in/
- http://bhutanonbike.blogspot.in/

Comment: To clarify, you want a Carnet de Passage to go to Pakistan, as an Indian citizen with an Indian-registered bike?

Comment: Yes Mark. I want a Carnet de Passage to go to Pakistan, as an Indian citizen with an Indian-registered bike.

Answer (score 11):

***Carnet de Passages en Douane*** is still required in 71 countries, which are parties to the Customs Convention on ATA Carnet. It is an internationally recognized Customs document entitling the holder to **TEMPORARILY** import a vehicle duty-free into countries, which normally require a deposit against import charges for such vehicles.

It is basically a promise, that you'll take your vehicle out of the country (you're visiting), when you leave.

**Who can provide Carnet de Passage in India**

The carnet, is not issued by a Government department in India (or elsewhere), rather by the Automobile Association of the country (or its affiliate and authorized member associations), which is an affiliated member of **Alliance Internationale de Tourisme**

The **[Federation of Automobile Associations of India](http://fiaa.co.in/about_fiaa.html)** is an affiliated member of the International federation and has the authority to provide Carnet de Passage through its member bodies, which cover different regions in India. You can approach any of these, based on where you stay in India:

- [The Automobile Association of Eastern India](http://www.aaei.info)
- [The Automobile Association of Southern India](http://www.aasindia.in)
- [Automobile Association of Upper India](http://www.aaui.org)
- The U.P. Automobile Association, Allahabad
- [The Western India Automobile Association](http://www.wiaaindia.com)

You can also get a Carnet through [FICCI](http://www.atacarnet.in/index.html) in India, though the applicants through FICCI cover a wider range of categories, and you might be asked to contact an Automobile Association for your case, since their primary audience is business people.

You cannot get a Carnet from a Government department. More than that, the amount you have been asked for (INR 10000), is what any authorized agency in India will ask for. The fee structure for Carnet can be verified from [this](http://www.atacarnet.in/pdf/ATA_Fee_Structure.pdf) link. The fee you have to pay, depends on the value of your vehicle (or goods, you're trying to carry).

I will advise you to get a Carnet, before you start your travel, to avoid any hassles at the border customs office, especially knowing that Pakistan is not that friendly with India, as compared to Nepal and Bhutan, and so rules will be strictly followed and adhered to (along with checking all required documents).

Comment: Excellent answer. I would also advise to obtain an IDL as well. +1